# MySQL error "Unknown column "sorting" in "where clause" very very odd

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So im trying to make a script that fetches all dates from my Database, and then adds 1 day to them, in the dd/mm/yy format, error trubleshooting worked fine, and my script works fine, other then that it cant upload to my SQL database....

ERROR: Unknown column "sorting" in 'where clause'

here it is:

```
<?      
$usernamedb = "goldacco"; // connect da jeg skal bruge det senere
$passworddb = "26102610asd";
$database = "goldacco_fb";
$server = "127.0.0.1";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $usernamedb, $passworddb);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

$i=0;
$f=0;

   $sql_sort = "SELECT sorting FROM feedback WHERE approved='1' ORDER BY sorting ASC"; // get lowest sorting
   $result_sort = mysql_query($sql_sort);
   $sorting = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_sort);

   $sorting[$f] = $sorting['sorting']; // 405



   $sql = "SELECT date FROM feedback WHERE approved='1' ORDER BY sorting ASC"; // get date
   $result_date = mysql_query($sql);

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_date) OR die(mysql_error())) { // værdigen jeg har gemt

       $olddate[$i] = $row['date'];

   $new_date[$i] = substr($olddate[$i], 0, -6); //  day

   $new_date[$i] = str_replace("/", null, $new_date[$i]); // fjern /

   $new_month[$i] = substr($olddate[$i], 2, -3); // month

   $new_month[$i] = str_replace("/", null, $new_month[$i]); // fjern /

   $new_year[$i] = substr($olddate[$i], 5-0); // år

   $new_year[$i] = str_replace("/", null, $new_year[$i]); // fjern /



   $new_date[$i] = $new_date[$i]+1;

  if ($new_date[$i] == 32) { // check om det er den 31, hvis ja, sæt til 0
    $new_date[$i] = 1;
    $new_month[$i] = $new_month[$i] +1;
  }

  if ($new_month[$i] == 13) { // check om det er den 12, hvis ja, sæt til 0
     $new_month[$i] = 1;
     $new_year[$i] = $new_month[$i] +1;
  }


  $new_date[$i] = sprintf("%02s", $new_date[$i]);
  $new_month[$i] = sprintf("%02s", $new_month[$i]);


  $new_total[$i] = $new_date[$i] . "/" . $new_month[$i] . "/" . $new_year[$i];

  $sql_into = "UPDATE feedback SET date=`$new_total` WHERE sorting=`$sorting[$f]`";
  $result_date = mysql_query($sql_into);

  $f++;
  $i++;
   }

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to print out the sql_into, in order to see what are you actually trying to update. Try to manually create this SQL with hard-coded values and execute it - to see if otherwise works.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your old questions. While they may no longer be important to you, they may be important to others who come across them.

Answer (score 3):

***Don't use backtick around string literals***. It should be single quotes. Backticks are for identifiers.

```
UPDATE feedback 
SET    date = '$new_total' 
WHERE  sorting='$sorting[$f]'
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: They are coming from the inside and have been cleaned

Comment: @JohnDoe then it should be fine `:D`

Comment: anyway, the problem is on line 35, the "While" statement =)
I think it has something to do with me defining "sorting" as an array and then using "ORDER BY 'sorting" to fetch new data